# 'Selection' is not defined react/jsx-no-undef

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Getting the error 'Selection' is not defined react/jsx-no-undef

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ReactDom from 'react-dom'
//import { Selection,Form, Button, FormGroup, FormControl, ControlLabel } from "react-bootstrap";

class index extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Selection>
                <h1> Something</h1>
            </Selection>
        )
    }
}
```

export default index

Answer (score 2):

You have your `Selection` import commented out, so the error is exactly what it says, `Selection` is not defined